# Closed-form expression (or good upper bound) for $\mathbb{E}\left[|X-\mathbb{E}X|^{\alpha}\right]$, where $X$ is binomial?

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

I am struggling to get either a closed-form expression, or as tight an upperbound as possible, for the quantity
$$
M_\alpha(X)\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=} \mathbb{E}\left[|X-\mathbb{E}X|^{\alpha}\right]
$$
where $X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(m,p)$ and $\alpha\in(1,2)$ (in other terms, a sort of "fractional moment about the mean"). In particular, any bound of the form
$$B(p,\alpha)= C m^{a} p^{b}$$ with $C > 0$, $a < \alpha$ and $b \geq 1$ would meet my goal... However, so far, the best I could get is either
$(mp)^\frac{\alpha}{2}$ (with Hölder)
or
$2m^\alpha p$ (with Edmundson-Madansky's inequality on $\phi\colon x\mapsto |x-mp|^\alpha$).

Has anyone ever encountered such problem, or has an idea on how to tackle it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hölder bound is about the best one can expect since the central limit theorem indicates that, when $m\to\infty$ with $p$ fixed, $M_\alpha(X)\sim\mathbb E[|Z|^\alpha](mp(1-p))^{\alpha/2}$ where $Z$ is standard normal.